# Custom SmartGWT FormItem

Tags: forms, gwt, customization, smartgwt

I've created a SmartGWT custom `FormItem` (by creating a child class `CustomTextItem` which extends `com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.TextItem` class), then I added an instance of `CustomTextItem` to some `DynamicForm`:

```
...
DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
form.setFields(new TextItem("text_field"), new CustomTextItem("custom_field"));
...
```

Now my problem is that I can't get the value of my customized object using `getValue()` method of the dynamic form:

```
Object text_value = form.getValue("text_field"); <<< this is OK
Object custom_value = form.getValue("custom_field"); <<< this always returns null
```

The question is that where does form object retrieves its values on sumbittion or validation?
 
I think I should override some `TextItem` class method or set some property in order to do this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you need to overwrite the `getValue` method in your `CustomTextItem` and return the value of the `CustomTextItem`

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi yes it does, you just have to know what to put in it. I don't think a simple `super.getValue()` would resolve it?

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi at least show us the code of your CustomTextItem

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value directly from your item like this **form.getItem("yourItemInstanceName").getValue()** 
You dont need to access the form for that.